# Getting the warning message 'Failed to resolve: com.symbol:emdk:9.1.1' on android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gradle

I'm currently trying to develop a basic barcode scanning app for a Zebra device. It's a TC57. The problem is, imports won't work for me in java. And whenever I try and sync my build.gradle file issues appear. I've included the relevant code below, is there anything I need to fix does anybody know why this is happening?

Thanks!

app/Build.Gradle

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdk 32
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.scanbarcode"
            minSdk 21
            targetSdk 32
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.symbol:emdk:9.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    releaseImplementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

project/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            maven { url "https://zebratech.jfrog.io/artifactory/EMDK-Android/" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0-alpha09'
        }
    }
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.scanbarcode">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ScanBarcode">
        <uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk" android:required="false"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "And whenever I try and sync my build.gradle file issues appear" -- could you explain what these issues are? If it is complaining that it cannot find that `com.symbol:emdk` artifact, try adding `jcenter()` to your `repositories` closure in the `allprojects` closure in your top-level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks that fixed it! Basically whenever I synced my file it was just telling me that the EMDK was not resolved and it took me back to the app/build.gradle depository. It wasn't an error, but just a warning and I couldn't access the imports in the java file.

Answer (score 1):

Symbol is distributing their artifacts via JCenter, a service of Bintray. In 2021 Bintray went through a period where they threatened to shut down JCenter, so developers abandoned it in droves. Among those changes was that Google removed `jcenter()` from the standard roster of artifact repositories to search in.

Long term, Symbol should do something else for distributing its artifacts.

Short term, you will need to add `jcenter()` back to your list of artifact repositories in Gradle.

Comment: What should we do now that jcenter is no more?

Comment: @WilliamVerhaeghe: You will need to ask Symbol that question. It appears that [they have not updated that artifact in over two years](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.symbol/emdk).

Comment: Yes, I just don't find details or source code. I'll have to ask my contacts. Would have been nice if you had another solution .